# Want to ask about the option to make index components private or public in the ID TOKEN account

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

With the hedera token ID, can I freely set public or private visibility options for indexes in my account?
For example: I want to publicly display degrees or education as badge tokens, but for some NFTs I own or for some services that I think should be private, then Can I have the option to hide it?

Hope to get an answer

Comment: What do you refer to as "indexes in my account"?

Comment: In general, all data that is stored on the network including both fungible tokens and non fungible tokens, are public on Hedera. Therefore these can be viewed by anyone who has access to the network, or via a DLT explorer (Hashscan).
If you wish to store private data, you will need to obscure it in some way.
e.g. You could perform client-side encryption of the data that you wish to keep private *prior to* putting it on network. That way only those possessing the necessary cryptographic keys would be able to view that data in a meaningful way. (Others would see random data).